# Ошибка при использовании тега <a href=" ">

Tags: html

День добрый у меня проблема, использую тег  указываю относительный путь и использую валидатор для проверки, выдает ошибку валидатор, хотя указываю абсолютный адрес без ошибок принимает:
вот адрес валидатора
https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea

Error: Bad value C:\Users\Jarvis\Desktop\business project\japanese.html for attribute href on element a: Illegal character in scheme data: \ is not allowed.
↩↩

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Укажите путь вашего основного файла

Comment: Благодарю за внимание!)

Comment: Ну, очевидно же, что обратные слэшы в web-адресе (пути) недопустимы.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `%5C` вместо `\`. RFC [2396](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) исключает `\` из списка разрешенных ascii-значений для использования в составе URI.

Answer (score 1):

```
C:/Users/Jarvis/Desktop/business project/japanese.html
```

Сделайте слеши в обратную сторону и не каких проблем.